# sed/awk or other: one-liner to increment a number by 1 keeping spacing characters

Tags: unix, shell, sed, awk

**EDIT**: I don't know in advance at which "column" my digits are going to be and I'd like to have a one-liner. Apparently sed doesn't do arithmetic, so maybe a one-liner solution based on awk?

I've got a string: (notice the spacing)

```
eh oh    37
```

and I want it to become:

```
eh oh    36
```

(so I want to keep the spacing)

Using *awk* I don't find how to do it, so far I have:

```
echo "eh oh   37" | awk '$3>=0&&$3<=99 {$3--} {print}'
```

But this gives:

```
eh oh 36
```

(the spacing characters where lost, because the field separator is ' ')

Is there a way to ask *awk* something like *"print the output using the exact same field separators as the input had"*?

Then I tried yet something else, using awk's *sub(..,..)* method:

```
' sub(/[0-9][0-9]/, ...) {print}'
```

but no cigar yet: I don't know how to reference the regexp and do arithmetic on it in the second argument (which I left with '...' for now).

Then I tried with sed, but got stuck after this:

```
echo "eh oh   37" | sed -e 's/\([0-9][0-9]\)/.../'
```

Can I do arithmetic from *sed* using a reference to the matching digits and have the output not modify the number of spacing characters?

Note that it's related to my question concerning Emacs and how to apply this to some (big) Emacs region (using a replace region with Emacs's *shell-command-on-region*) but it's not an identical question: this one is specifically about how to "keep spaces" when working with awk/sed/etc.

Comment: I know this would be straightforward with perl - you can have `split` give you the delimiters as well as the fields.

Comment: You can manage this in awk by completely ignoring its field-splitting, and just doing some regex stuff on `$0`, but it's kind of inelegant. Is perl an option?

Comment: @Jefromi: sure, Perl is an option... But I'm interested in the fugly awk version too :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a variation on **ghostdog74's** answer that does not require the number to be anchored at the end of the string. This is accomplished using `match` instead of relying on the number to be in a particular position.

This will replace the first number with its value minus one:

```
$ echo "eh oh    37      aaa     22    bb" | awk '{n = substr($0, match($0, /[0-9]+/), RLENGTH) - 1; sub(/[0-9]+/, n); print }'
eh oh    36      aaa     22    bb
```

Using `gsub` there instead of `sub` would replace both the "37" and the "22" with "36". If there's only one number on the line, it doesn't matter which you use. By doing it this way, though, it will handle numbers with trailing whitespace plus other non-numeric characters that may be there (after some whitespace).

If you have `gawk`, you can use `gensub` like this to pick out an arbitrary number within the string (just set the value of `which`):

```
$ echo "eh oh    37      aaa     22    bb    19" |
    awk -v which=2 'BEGIN { regex = "([0-9]+)\\>[^0-9]*";
        for (i = 1; i < which; i++) {regex = regex"([0-9]+)\\>[^0-9]*"}}
        { match($0, regex, a);
        n = a[which] - 1;                    # do the math
        print gensub(/[0-9]+/, n, which) }'
eh oh    37      aaa     21    bb    19
```

The second (`which=2`) number went from 22 to 21. And the embedded spaces are preserved.

It's broken out on multiple lines to make it easier to read, but it's copy/pastable.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ echo "eh oh    37" | awk '{n=$NF+1; gsub(/[0-9]+$/,n) }1'
eh oh    38
```

or

```
$ echo "eh oh    37" | awk '{n=$NF+1; gsub(/..$/,n) }1'
eh oh    38
```

Answer (score 2):

something like

```
number=`echo "eh oh 37" | grep -o '[0-9]*'`
sed 's/$number/`expr $number + 1`/'
```

Comment: @Paul Creasey: so you can't do this from "inside" sed? You need a temporary variable?

Comment: @WizardOfOdds: Yeah, sed doesn't do arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
$ echo "eh oh   37" | awk -F'[ \t]' '{$NF = $NF - 1;} 1'
eh oh   36
```

Comment: Nice: the idea here is we stop treating spans of whitespace as delimiters, but instead honor each whitespace character as a delimiter. Note though that this will replace any tab in the input line with OFS (a space). That may be undesired.

Answer (score 0):

The solution will not preserve the number of decimals, so if the number is 10, then the result is 9, even if one would like to have 09.

I did not write the shortest possible code, it should stay readable

Here I construct the printf pattern using RLENGTH so it becomes %02d (2 being the length of the matched pattern)

```
$ echo "eh oh    10      aaa     22    bb" |
    awk '{n = substr($0, match($0, /[0-9]+/), RLENGTH)-1 ; 
          nn=sprintf("%0" RLENGTH "d", n)
          sub(/[0-9]+/, nn);
          print 
         }'
eh oh    09      aaa     22    bb
```