# Mac OS X sed regexp

Tags: macos, sed

I am trying to do simple find replace digit while adding a value but failing to do so under Mac OS X, e.g.

```
echo "abc top: 234px" |sed -E 's/top:[[:space:]]*([0-9]+)/echo $(echo "\1+16"|bc)/g'
```

which should output: `"abc top: 250px"`

Instead it outputs: `abc echo $(echo "234+16"|bc)px`

Comment: Using hard quotes (`'`) is preventing `$(echo "\1+16"|bc)` from being expanded.

Comment: @PaulR what is work around then

Comment: You just need to fix your quoting, i.e. don't use hard quotes around stuff you want to be expanded.

Comment: would you add a fixed version as answer ? When I remove quotes it gives me `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('` error

Comment: It looks like this won't work even when you fix the quoting, since you can't do arithmetic in sed - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687009/sed-awk-or-other-one-liner-to-increment-a-number-by-1-keeping-spacing-character + consider using awk instead.

Comment: I got the idea from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348432/how-to-find-replace-and-increment-a-matched-number-with-sed-awk

Comment: In the question you were looking at they were using GNU sed - since you're using OS X you don't have this (which is also why the `-r` option doesn't work). Use awk or perl - it will be much easier.

Comment: It's not the `-r` so much as the `/e` modifier flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot refer back to the back-reference using an external command -- when `echo | bc` is evaluated (once you fix the quoting so that they are evaluated at all in the first place), the `sed` script has not yet been parsed.

What you can do is switch to a tool which allows for arithmetic on captured values.

```
echo "abc top: 234px" |
perl -pe 's/(top:\s*)(\d+)/ sprintf("%s%i", $1, 16+$2)/ge'
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an `awk`

```
echo "abc top: 234px" | awk '$NF=$NF+16"px"'
abc top: 250px
```

Some more robust with search for `top`:

```
echo "abc top: 234px" | awk '/top:/ {$NF=$NF+16"px";print}'
abc top: 250px
```

---

Here you do not need the format prefix `px`:

```
echo "abc top: 234px" | awk 'sub(/[0-9]+/,$NF+16)'
abc top: 250px
```

or

```
echo "abc top: 234px" | awk '/top:/ {sub(/[0-9]+/,$NF+16);print}'
abc top: 250px
```

Answer (score 1):

Difficult with sed, but here's a perl solution:

```
$ echo "abc top: 234px" | perl -pe 's/(\d+)/16 + $1/ge'
abc top: 250px
```